Flutter integration tests report shows 0 tests but actually runs tests
I'm running flutter integration tests (instrumentation tests) using flutter integration_driver
There are two ways of running the tests:
1. Using flutter driver command
I run flutter driver with some parameters, it works fine. I see lots of logs and can find the failures as well.
flutter driver --target=integration_test/main_test.dart --flavor rc  --driver=test_driver/main_test.dart --dart-define=set=firebase --dart-define=test-set=all 

2. Using flutter build gradlew
Now if I run the tests using gradlew, I can see the tests are run, but it doesn't show the results in report form.
The command I run:
  flutter build apk --debug --flavor rc
  ./gradlew app:assembleRcDebugAndroidTest
  ./gradlew app:connectedRcDebugAndroidTest -Ptarget=integration_test/main_test.dart \
      -Pdart-defines="base64-parameters-here"

I can see the tests being executed on emulator. Below are command output on console:
Full logs here.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRcDebug'...                           19.8s
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-rc-debug.apk.
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
WARNING:The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated.
It was removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
Please remove it from `gradle.properties`.
WARNING:DSL element 'dexOptions' is obsolete and should be removed.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
Using it has no effect, and the AndroidGradle plugin optimizes dexing automatically.

> Configure project :flutter_lib
WARNING:DSL element 'dexOptions' is obsolete and should be removed.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
Using it has no effect, and the AndroidGradle plugin optimizes dexing automatically.
WARNING:Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.
...
This Android Gradle plugin (7.1.0-rc01) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=34
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 34
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.1.0-rc01) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33
WARNING:The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (30.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 7.1.0-rc01.
Android SDK Build Tools 30.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :flutter_lib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/name/source/comp-client/flutter_apps/flutter_lib/android/src/main/java/com/comp/flutter_lib/android_lib/DocParser.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :app:compileRcDebugKotlin
'compileRcDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 17) and 'compileRcDebugKotlin' task (current target is 1.8) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
By default will become an error since Gradle 8.0+! Read more: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/target-validation
Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain
...

> Task :app:dexBuilderRcDebugAndroidTest
WARNING:/Users/name/source/schema/flutter_apps/testapp/build/app/intermediates/javac/rcDebugAndroidTest/classes/com/comp/testapp/test/BuildConfig.class: D8: One or more classes has class file version >= 56 which is not officially supported.
WARNING:/Users/name/source/schema/flutter_apps/testapp/build/app/intermediates/javac/rcDebugAndroidTest/classes/com/comp/testapp/MainActivityTest.class: D8: One or more classes has class file version >= 56 which is not officially supported.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 44s
842 actionable tasks: 28 executed, 814 up-to-date
...

This Android Gradle plugin (7.1.0-rc01) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=34
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 34
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.1.0-rc01) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33
WARNING:The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (30.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 7.1.0-rc01.
Android SDK Build Tools 30.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRcDebug
Error: unable to find directory entry in pubspec.yaml: /Users/name/source/schema/flutter_apps/testapp/assets/yaml_mapping_files/

> Task :app:compileRcDebugKotlin
'compileRcDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 17) and 'compileRcDebugKotlin' task (current target is 1.8) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
By default will become an error since Gradle 8.0+! Read more: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/target-validation
Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

> Task :app:connectedRcDebugAndroidTest0s]
Starting 0 tests on Pixel_6_Pro_API_34(AVD) - 14

Test results saved as file:/Users/name/source/schema/flutter_apps/testapp/build/app/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/flavors/rc/Pixel_6_Pro_API_34(AVD)%20-%2014/test-result.pb. Inspect these results in Android Studio by selecting Run > Import Tests From File from the menu bar and importing test-result.pb.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2h 19m 59s
863 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 854 up-to-date

In test-result.pb I do not see any tests run.
